# scipy optimization solve non linear equations with array?

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I have to solve the follow sistem of equation :

```
f1 = -k1 + self.f(
    self.time[i] + (0.5 + np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt,
    self.u[i] + 0.25 * self.dt * k1 + (0.25 + np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt * k2) 
f2 = -k2 + self.f(
    self.time[i] + (0.5 - np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt,
    self.u[i] + (0.25 - np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt * k1 + 0.25 * self.dt * k2)
```

Searching in the previous post I found this solutions :

```
def equations(variable):
    k1,k2 = variable
    f1 = -k1 + self.f(
        self.time[i] + (0.5 + np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt,
        self.u[i] + 0.25 * self.dt * k1 + (0.25 + np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt * k2)
    f2 = -k2 + self.f(
        self.time[i] + (0.5 - np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt,
        self.u[i] + (0.25 - np.sqrt(3)/6) * self.dt * k1 + 0.25 * self.dt * k2)
    return np.array([f1,f2]).ravel()     #.reshape(2,)  

k1, k2 = fsolve(equations, (self.u[i],self.u[i]))
```

But does't works for me, because my `self.u[i]` in on `len(self.u[i]) == 2` 
how can I deal in this situations??

I got this error:

```
    k1,k2 = variable
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

but I don't know how to fix it , if i simply pass 2 float `(2.,2.)` I got  this :

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.
Shape should be (2,) but it is (4).
```

and if i left the `.ravel()` on the return array i got the same error but :

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'equations'.
Shape should be (2,) but it is (2,2).
```

please may somebody help me to come up with this ?

```
class ImpRK4 :
    def __init__(self, fun , t0, tf, dt , y0):
        self.func = fun
        self.t0=t0
        self.tf=tf
        self.dt=dt
        self.u0=y0
        self.n = round((tf-t0)/dt)
        self.time  = np.linspace(self.t0, self.tf, self.n+1 )
        self.u     = np.array([self.u0  for i in range(self.n+1) ])

    def f(self,ti,ui):
         return  np.array([functions(ti,ui) for functions in self.func])     

    def solve(self): 
       for i in range(len(self.time)-1):
            def equations(variable):
                k1,k2 = variable
                f1 = -k1 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5+np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+0.25*self.dt* k1+ (0.25+ np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt*k2) 
                f2 = -k2 + self.f(self.time[i]+ (0.5-np.sqrt(3)/6)* self.dt , self.u[i]+(0.25-np.sqrt(3)/6)*self.dt *k1 + 0.25*self.dt* k2)
                return np.array([f1,f2]).ravel() #.reshape(2,)  

            k1 , k2 = fsolve(equations,(2,2)) #(self.u[i],self.u[i]))
            self.u[i+1] = self.u[i] + self.dt/2* (k1 + k2)

       plt.plot(self.time,self.u)
       plt.show()    

def main():
    func00 = lambda t,u : -10*(t-1)*u[0]

    func01 = lambda t,u : u[1] 
    func02 = lambda t,u : (1-u[0]**2)*u[1] - u[0]

    func0x = np.array([func00])
    func0 = np.array([func01,func02])

    y01 = np.array([1.,1.])
    t0 = 0. 
    tf = 2.      
    u0 = y01   
    dt = 0.008 

    y0  = np.array([np.exp(-5)])
    diffeq = ImpRK4(func0,t0,tf,dt,y01)    

    #diffeq.solve()
    #diffeq = ImpRK4(func0x,t0,tf,dt,y0) ## with single equations works
    diffeq.solve()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Ok here the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Please write done in a legible manner the equations themselves and then provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok I will prepare ! sorry!!

Comment: From the reference "func: A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length". So as you mentioned this doesn't work with fsolve. A different note: np.concatenate((f1,f2)) is equal to np.array((f1,f2)).ravel()

Comment: and with other solver works ?